# Как сделать прозрачную авторизацию apache в AD?

Tags: apache, apache-modules

Необходимо авторизовывать пользователей на интранет сайте, однако при этом юзер не должен вводить никаких логинов-паролей. Пока удалось реализовать простую авторизацию через `ldap` с запросом логина-пароля, но это не вариант. Можно ли представленный ниже вариант привести к нужному виду? Что почитать? Гугление пока результатов не дает....

```
Directory />  
Options FollowSymLinks  
AllowOverride All  
AuthName "MY Access"
AuthType Basic    
AuthBasicProvider ldap  
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative On  
AuthLDAPUrl ldap://10.10.11.80/ou=ITdep,dc=myorg,dc=mycomp,dc=edu?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)  
AuthLDAPBindDN dummyUser@myorg.mycomp.edu  
AuthLDAPBindPassword "sU^^erPa$$worD"  
Require valid-user  
/Directory>
```

Comment: Если у вас AD, то может лучше IIS юзать?

Comment: тут речь идет о проекте, который изначально сделан на линуксе.. к нему сейчас делается web-морда. понятно, что лучше использовать родную среду, но тут никак...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, я сделал через керберос. Получилось довольно легко и быстро. [Вот](http://acksyn.org/diary/?p=460) статейка.